# Stored Proc which returns result by Dynamic SQL doesn't emit column names

Tags: sql, linq, dynamic

I have an SP that will potentially gather up millions of rows, this SP generated this result set by Dynamic SQL. However, the SP is called from LINQ and LINQ does not recognize the columns that should be returned by this SP.

If I create a temp table LINQ will recognize but then I'm not sure if the SP first has to fill that TEMP table before giving control back or if it's no different than not using a temp table in the SP.

Meaning, will using a temp table so that LINQ can recognize the columns degrade performance or behave differently than if I don't use a temp table?

Still if I don't use a temp table then LINQ can't get the columns so it's a quandary.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: The result set should have a fixed number of columns and you should do the pivoting on your application to avoid this kind of problems

Comment: Thanks Lemak, not sure I understand what you're saying though. The set does have a fixed number of columns, it;s just that they are defined inside the dynamic sql and so LINQ won't recognize them.

Comment: Are you referring to LINQ-to-SQL? "called from LINQ" doesn't explicitly explain what framework you're using - you can "call from LINQ" when using other ORMs.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SET FMTONLY ON
EXEC dbo.yourProc
SET FMTONLY OFF
```

This is how Linq-to-Sql will call your proc to determine the column names.  Also, if you proc has any parameters, Linq-to-Sql will send nulls.

If this errors, or produces no results, Linq-to-Sql won't be able to use the results from the proc.  You should be able to tweak it from here to get it to run.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a stored proc to return the result sets try using a table-valued function instead.

Within a table-valued function you declare the table structure that is expected to be returned so LINQ should be able to use this.

For more information on Table-Valued functions visit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165.aspx

Utilizing them with LINQ: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386954.aspx

Hope this helps!